# Selenium 4.0(Java) + Cucumber + Browserstack + Applitools

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-java, applitools

I want to create test automation framework which has Cucumber, Selenium Webdriver 4.0 version with Cross browser capabilities, which will get executed on Browserstack and visual validation through applitools.

Any suggestions will be far helpful

Comment: Please ask a specific question related to something you tried.

Comment: Not yet started, wanted to plan the work based on inputs which I will get here

Comment: Usually you should do some research first, try to implement an here just ask for a specific question and not general stuff like a guide, tutorial etc. This platform is for questions related to a specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is Sophie from Applitools :)
You can consult [this article](https://help.applitools.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006914812-Behavioral-Driven-Development-BDD-) that describe the integration of Applitools Eyes with a BDD tools, using "Cucumber" as an example.

I hope that helps.